# SQL: Picking out things from the list

Tags: sql

I don't know how to ask SQL to filter for one word. I will give you a simple example:

```
SELECT * FROM shopping.list LIMIT 10
```

Let's pretend that 3 of those 10 items are sweets and I want the SQL to filter through the shopping.list dictionary and then show those three sweets.

Comment: It's better to provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: `select * from shopping.list where item='sweets' limit 3`?

Comment: It would be very useful to see what you've tried so far, it might give us more of a clue of what you're trying to achieve!  Have you tried a `where` clause? Why didn't that work? Did you try `like`? etc.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume that your shopping.list table has a column called name where you store the names of the items in your shopping list.
You could write something like:

```
 Select * from shopping.list where name like '%sweets%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you need a column that is a category, such as 'Sweet', 'Vegetable' etc.
You can then use a `Where` clause to check this column for 'Sweet'.

If you are confident you know which items are sweets then just a `Where list in ('Chew Sweet', 'Boiled Sweet')`

Answer (score 0):

Lets start from the scratch for your better understanding.

There are multiple platforms of SQL..
Such as:

1) Oracle,

2) PostgreSQL,

3) SQL Server
etc..

and I'm using `SQL Server` approach.

To create table the syntax with example of creating a table is as follows:

```
Create table Shopping
(
 id int identity(1,1) primary key,
 ItemName varchar(50)
)
```

Now the table is created and is available in schema to be manipulated. I will add some rows into this table. Following is the syntax to insert rows into the table.

```
insert into shopping values('Cheese Cake'), ('Bread Pudding'), ('Waffle')
```

above insert syntax is inserting multiple rows. Each row insertion is separated by a comma. After every comma it reads it as a new row and value is inserted respectively as table definition defined above.

Now comes the time to fetch this data for which I will write a Select query which is:

```
Select Id, ItemName 
from Shopping 
where ItemName IN ('Cheese Cake', 'Waffle')
```

The Select Query above will fetch the Data as it is asked to bring. After select query columns that needed are mentioned then we provide the table name where these columns are available. To get the specific result only we use the `WHERE` clause in which we define the column name and the value.

Execute it and it will return a result in the following manner:

[image]